# Bash for windows 10 not opening a program

Tags: windows-10, bash, bash-scripting, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run chrome and get its pid from bash for win10.

When I run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` I'm getting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe: command not found`.

I can do the same on mingw and it runs Chrome there just fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: Even when I flip the \ to be / in the path I still get: `bash: C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe: No such file or directory`

Comment: Possibly the nature of Chrome itself is preventing this? Multiple copies of the EXE run at once.

Comment: You are getting "no such file or directory" because the bash environment your using isn't aware of your path to that exectuable.

Comment: [Run Windows executable from bash](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/333) even if you were to mount the directory and run the application it still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're on one of the fast ring Windows 10 builds (starting at Creators Edition aka 1703), or have gone through specific setup steps, bash on Windows won't run Windows executables.

Also, the Windows drives are mounted under /mnt/ e.g.,

```
/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
```

Comment: You should use the correct terms.  "fast track" isn't a thing.  It's called "Fast ring" and 'Slow ring".  But you are right.  This will be a feature in the, Creators Edition aka 1703, because of the migration Ubuntu 16.04 and the added capability.  [New Feature: Windows / Ubuntu Interoperability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#build-14951)